# SQL Server Scalar Function to return single AD Name

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I need help. I'm wanting to create a scalar function on SQL Server that I can pass the employee ID and it will return the AD name for that person.

I can run a straight query all day long and it works like below:

```
DECLARE @TargetUser VARCHAR(100)
SET @TargetUser = '136881'

DECLARE @QueryStr VARCHAR(1000), @LDAPStr VARCHAR(100)
SET @LDAPStr = 'LDAP://myserver.edu/OU=People,DC=myserver,DC=edu'
SET @QueryStr = 'SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, ''SELECT name FROM ''''' 
+ @LDAPStr + ''''' WHERE objectClass = ''''User'''' AND employeeID = ''''' 
+ @TargetUser + ''''''')'

EXECUTE (@QueryStr)
```

I try and make it into a function and I get a linked server error.

Here is what I have and it gives me the linked server error:

```
GO
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[fnGetAdName] (@EMPLID nvarchar(11))
Returns nvarchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @QueryStr VARCHAR(1000), @LDAPStr VARCHAR(100), @ret VARCHAR(50)
SET @LDAPStr = 'LDAP://myserver.edu/OU=People,DC=myserver,DC=edu'
SET @QueryStr = 'SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, ''SELECT name FROM ''''' 
+ @LDAPStr + ''''' WHERE objectClass = ''''User'''' AND employeeID = ''''' 
+ @EMPLID + ''''''')'

EXEC  @ret = @QueryStr

RETURN @ret
END
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You cannot use dynamic SQL in a function.  Why do you need dynamic SQL anyway?

Comment: Because OpenQuery will not allow you to pass a value to it.